# How to include message body in the mailchimp API via php

Tags: php, mailchimp

Am trying to create campaign/send mail to my **mailchimp** account so I referenced solutions found here [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427926/how-to-create-a-campaign-using-mailchimp-v3-0) which works great via the code below

**My issues:**

Now from the mailchimp api, I did not see where to include the **message body** or the **message content** in the api.
Has anyone done this. can someone help me out

here is the mailchimp API
[API link](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/)

```
$data = array("recipients" => array("list_id" => "205d96e6b4"), "type" => "regular", "settings" => array("subject_line" => "Subject", "title" => "Title", "reply_to" => "test@gmail.com", "from_name" => "Test", "folder_id" => "8888969b77"));
$data = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(    
   //Sample url
   CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "authorization: apikey <your_apikey>"
   ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
   $response = $err;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content/#%20 and click on Edit.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use two API,  one for sending mail and upon that I will get the campaign id to send content message via the second API that you showed me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple works by sending mails details via the first API is I posted above. On successful message, The campaign API is retrieved from the above result response which is then used to send message content to mailchip